# Complex integral, integrating along a line segment

Tags: complex-analysis

I'm stuck with a complex line segment, I'm supposed to integrate $1/(1+z^2)$ dz along the line segment from $z=1$ to $z=1+i$, no matter how I do it, I'm getting the angle wrong, is there anyone who can show me how I'm supposed to attack a problem like this?

Comment: In your problem there is only a line segment: which angle are you referring to?

Comment: What your approach would have been, if the problem was $\int_{1}^{2}\frac{dx}{x^2+1}$?

Comment: Is there something really different, since we are away from the singularities of $\frac{1}{z^2+1}$, occurring at $z\in\{-i,+i\}$?

Comment: Sorry, not really meaning an angle, I was referring to the pi-term, didnt mean angle, I take that one back

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no reason to bother with any angle nor is there any "pi" term.  Writing z= x+ iy, we can write the line from 1 to 1+ i as x= 1, y= t, so z= 1+ it with t going from 0 to 1.  Since the real part is constant, that is $\int_0^1\frac{1}{1+ (1+it)^2w} (idt)= i\int_0^1 \frac{dt}{1+ 1+ 2it- t^2}= -i\int_0^1 \frac{dt}{t^2- 2it- 2}$.  That looks like a candidate for "partial fractions".

Comment: Is it wrong to just split up the (1+z^2) to (z-i)(z+i) and integrate over z ? is there a reason for me to go from z to t?

Comment: I'm getting to the point (i/2)log((-1-i)/-3-i)), unsure of where I go from here, am I on the right track ?

Comment: I think I got it right now good sir, thank you, can you help me with one last thing, I had to use a standard table of integrals to solve it, but I dont know why, one part of the question is to explan why I can use a standard table of integrals.